# Django passing data to html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Ok, I'm stuck and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have database and i need to fetch data from it and render it in HTML. I've watched few tutorials and it doesn't seem hard but it's not working for me.
this is my view:

```
def get_all_subjects(request):
    all_subjects = Predmeti.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {"Predmeti": all_subjects})
```

and this is home.html:

```
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Hi {{ user.email }}!
        <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
        <table>
        {% for predmet in Predmeti %}

            <tr>
            <td>{{ predmet.ime }}</td>
            <td>{{ predmet.kod }}</td>
            <td>{{ predmet.bodovi }}</td>
            <td>{{ predmet.izborni }} </td>

            <td>
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'upisni list' id=predmet.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit"> Dodaj</button>
            </form>
            </td>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
        </table>
{% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

It just says hi to username. Any help is welcome

Comment: is your data saved to a default database?

Comment: does you data actually contain any records?

Comment: Is the logout button getting displayed?

Comment: I can supposed the variable's name `Predmeti` you pass is not well enough. Maybe there's a conflict with the name of your model or something like this. Have you tried a different name for the variable passed to the template?

Answer (score 1):

as return do this:

```
return render(request, 'home.html', locals())
```

then in html:

```
{% for predmet in all_subjects %}
    {{ predmet.ime }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: still does not display data

Comment: @ŠimeGalac then check if there is some data in database related to this model or if you are authenticated.

Comment: there is data and I am authenticated, hate it when I stuck on trivial stuff

Comment: @ŠimeGalac debug if you can add some html text inside loop, and check if you see it. If yes then print `all_subjects` in you view.

Comment: obviously, data is not in the all_subjects list

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, it was beacuse in settings.py I used home.html as django default TemplateView

```
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'),  name='home'),
```

did this:

```
path('upisnilist/', views.get_all_subjects, name='predmeti' )
```

and works fine